# Why did IBM 7030 or IBM 360 use byte and word addressing simultaneously

Tags: memory, ibm, ram, ibm360

In 1950s machines had a *36 bit words*. And in this *word* we could pack symbols using *6 bits*. And to fetch this symbols from the *word* programmer should do it [using bit manipulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit_computing).

In 1961 IBM released 7030 machine that also had [*word addressable* memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7030_Stretch#Memory). On the other hand, this machine was the first one which used term *byte* with *8 bits*.

My first assumption about "why we need a *byte* term" was the following:

If this *8 bits* were addressable, we could store and get any *8 bit* symbol from memory without any bit manipulations. But if memory was *word addressable* my assumption rises a contradiction: how we could address a single *byte* if memory was *word addressable*?

So my question is: what was the point of using term *byte* in IBM 7030, if memory was *word addressable* and we can not get any benefits from *byte*?

Comment: I think your conclusion that there would only be a benefit from introducing the term *byte* if the machine was byte adressable is wrong. If you repeatedly need to refer to a unit of 8 bits, it makes sense to give that unit a name, even if it exists only conceptually.

Comment: Also, maybe somepne who knows more about the 7030 and the 360 than I do can clear this up: Did either of these machines use byte adressable memory? If not, we should change the headline of the question.

Comment: 7030=word addressable. 360=byte addressable.  I *think* the 360 introduced byte-addressable memory.

Comment: @another-dave Erm yes and no. The /360 uses a byte address, but the 7030 as well. At least in the sense that several instructions can explicite address a byte section within a word. So while the basic access to memory is word wise, from a programmers view it can be byte wise - although, not always linear. The versatile data definition mechanics of a 7030 are a bit too complex to be described with a single term like byte or word addressing.

Comment: You do a secondary addressing of a byte in the word with a bit mask instruction. The byte location is just not encoded in the memory address but somewhere else. The machine isn't byte addressable doesn't means the program isn't either.

Comment: @Raffzahn  - I specifically meant the case where real memory_address and memory_address+1 were 8 bits apart.  I exclude the case where instructions could read a fullword and extract a part thereof - they're not byte-addressable memory.   But yeah, the 7030 was a marvel to behold: innovation up to the eyeballs and a failure at the same time. Second-system syndrome before it was cool. And I mean that in admiration.

Comment: @another-dave Well, on a 7030 24-bit-memory-address and 24-bit-memory-address+1 is exactly one bit apart :)) Also, "real memory address" on a /360 was always at least a 16 bit (there was never a /360 with core blocks smaller than 18 bit), usually rather 32 or 64. So the lower bits of a 'byte address'  as always a word address plus a byte address within. Like on a 7030 any write on less than a memory word was a RMW cycle. The 7030 is one of the most flexible designs I can think of - clearly a product of a time before possibilities got reduced to what we take today as granted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Please see as well [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15327/6659), as it's kind of an extension]*

> Why did IBM 7030 or IBM 360 use byte and word addressing simultaneously

Not sure what's with /360 reference here, as it's uses byte addressing (*1).

The 7030 in contrast used word and bit addressing.

Word addressing of 18 bit when it was about words, and bit addressing in the form of a 24 bit address when it was about 'bytes'. A word address is always stored in the first 18 bits of an instruction word (32/64 bit), followed by 6 bit holding the bit address for instructions accessing chunks of a word (a majority). Most of them contained as well the bit length (up to 64). (*2,*3)

> In 1950s machines had a 36 bit words.

Some had, others had different word sizes, like 18, 22 or 72.

> And in this word we could pack symbols using 6 bits. And to fetch this symbols from the word programmer should do it using bit manipulations.

Some supported 6 bit sizes, other none or arbitrary.

> In 1961 IBM released 7030 machine that also had word addressable memory. On the other hand, this machine was the first one which used term byte with 8 bits.

No. While [Werner Buchholz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Buchholz) did coin the term [Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#History) when working on the 7030, it didn't describe a unit of 8 bit, but a variable size definition for a bit group of 1 to 8 bits (*4), defined in each instruction as needed. Others took it the same way, simply as an arbitrary number of bits anywhere between 4 and 9 (*5), depending on machine and/or language, 'bitten' out of a word.

> If this 8 bits were addressable, we could store and get any 8 bit symbol from memory without any bit manipulations. But if memory was word addressable my assumption rises a contradiction: how we could address a single byte if memory was word addressable?

By extracting that byte? A byte access in a 7030 consists of a word address and a byte address within. Byte access was done by using a *data description* (dds) made up of *mode*, *field length* and *byte size*

> So my question is: what was the point of using term byte in IBM 7030, if memory was word addressable and we can not get any benefits from byte?

Byte in the 7030 sense isn't a fixed sub unit of a word like today, but a variable length unit within a variable length fiel within a word.

At that point it may be helpful to peek into the [7030 Assembler manual](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/IBM/Stretch/pdfs/13-08/102634321.pdf), as about half of it is dedicated to data definition and how this is handled. It's worlds away from what is canon today and way more like some HLL (*6).

---

*1 - Another standard IBM did set. All addressing was bytewise, independent of word length or position. It simplified memory access to what we now take for granted.

- All addresses had the same format and size
- All were byte addresses
- No address calculation between data types needed
- Halfwords and words are fixed length collection of fixed size bytes
- The only speciality of words and halfwords was that they had to be alligned to their size.

All this we take for granted today and many have a hard time to understand that the world before the /360 was different. More colourful but more chaotic as well.

*2 - Any length up to 64 bits could be used and bit addresses warped to word addresses. So it was not only possible to pack 3 21-bit integers into a word without any need for conversion, but as well spread such bitfields across words - like 30 12-bit integer over 3 words :)

*3 - I personally thing the object orientated bit-mongering of Intel's 432 was quite influenced by the way the 7030 handeled it's data.

*4 -  The Assembler used default sizes of 1, 4 or 8, depending on the mode field, if none were given explicite or by data definitions.

*5 - Or simply used byte as a term for any bit defined chunk different from a word - as in "A Bite from a Word" - like the PDP-10s bit field operations handling variable length sections of 1..36 bit were as well called byte.

*6 - In some way it shows the quintessence of computer development between back then and today. In the old days computers were enhanced to offer instructions the programmer can use deliver the task, while today instructions are simplified and  programmers work hard to please the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is the best answer I have ever seen among all of the answers for all of my question at all stack overflow resources!
Thank you SO much for your effort. One more question. According to the link that you provided to 7030 asm. I didn’t get the following: it seems that 7030 used 6 bits to store symbol, but used 1 or 4 or 8 bits for byte. How it was possible to fetch symbol from a word?

Comment: @NoNameQA It can use any byte size between 1 and 8 - wich includes 6. 1,2 and 4 are only default sizes depending on the instruction, when no other size is given. By defining data for example `DD (BU, 60, 6), DO NOT PANIC Q` would define a data structure, holding unsigned binary (BU) in fields of 60 bit with bytes of 6 bit, to be prefilled with the conversion of the 15 characters following (' DO NOT PANIC '). Q in this case marks the string termination.  Fetching could now be done symbolic by using the data name and a byte offset, which gets turned into a bitaddress by the assembler.

Comment: your answers are music to my ears! Thank you for detailed explanation! The last question. Werner Buchholz defined byte like `part of the word that contains from 1 to 8 bits`. Was number 8 some specific number that was connected with some CPU internal structure or it was just some magic number?

Comment: @NoNameQA I added more to the answer. No, 8 was simply what could be put in a 3 bit field offered by instructions that handled more than a byte at once. Essetially all instructions when the machine had to handle the advancement of bit addresses for multiple elements. Other instructions allow sizes between 1 and 64. Check teh instruction encoding shown in the manual.

Comment: Thank you! I found on page 13 bullet 7: `BS_3 Byte Size` which has format `|21 bits | 3 bits|`  Is it page that you are referred to? Even if so I'm still confused since 3 bits can hold value from 0 to 7, not from 1 to 8.

Comment: @NoNameQA Erm ... you're trying something, right? :) How many values are there in the range of 0..7, and ho many do you need to hold the length of the bit field being 1..8? I mean, noone in his right mind (at least back then and real programmers) would waste another bit, making it 4 bits,  just to preserve the otherwise illegal length of zero? Not to mention adding 7 more illegal values and complicating the decoder?

Comment: `Erm ... you're trying something, right?` :)) I'm just want to make sure that I understood everything correctly. Thank you one more time. You are amazing!

Comment: There were also multiple 40-bit machines in the 50s (all IAS lineage machines I am aware of).

Comment: I have re-read you answer one more time and found one confusing detail. if I understood you correctly, you said that 7030 used 24 bits for addressing individual byte inside the word. First 18 bits were word address. Than we have 6 bits . And you said that last 3 bits were size of the byte. So it means that 3 bits between 18 and 3 last bits were byte’s address inside the word. But if last 6 bits were 111 111 how did CPU understand, that this is 63rd byte of size 1 bit and not 7th byte of size 8 bits?

Comment: @NoNameQA No, the 24-bit address points to a bit, not a byte. The byte length is independent and stored at different location within the instruction. It's not part of the address. Yes, B'111111' is the last bit in a word (Note, IBM counts from left to right, to bit#63 is value 1 of its word when seen as a 64-bit integer) This addressing simply continues into the next word. After all, what is the result when incrementing an address like `000000 100000 000000 111111` by 1? It's `000000 100000 000001 000000`, right? And that simply is the first bit of the next word, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Thank you! I do not want to extend our conversation further, so I have create separate question about byte size here https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15318/why-was-the-maximum-byte-size-of-8-bits-on-ibm-7030 If you have time, please take a look. There I've tried to explain what I do not understand.

Answer (score 7):

'Byte' was used before it meant '8 bits' and It was used on machines that had word-addressable memory.  The point was for the program to be able to read and write data of less than a word size.

The PDP-10, with which I am familiar, had "load byte" and "deposit byte" instructions which could read any part of a word, sized from 0 to 36 bits.  As far as memory was concerned, whole words would be transferred; the ALU would handle the shifting and masking required to extract/insert the designated field.  Since memory was word-addressable,  a special address format was required for these instructions - it had a standard address, and also offset-in-word and size-of-byte fields (6 bits each).

The byte instructions were heavily used, for example, for manipulating text. The standard format was 7-bit bytes (ASCII encoding) packed 5 to a word, with one bit left over.  The byte instructions made it trivial to process such a format.

Absent such instructions, the programmer would have had to write the and mask instructions himself.

Stretch (the 7030) was similar.  It had a standard 18-bit address for word operations, and an extended format that specified the exact bitfield on which to operate. As with the PDP-10, the term 'byte' is used regardless of the bit count of the field.

'Individual characters, or bytes, in a field may also be varied in length' -- see the section on Integer Arithmetic in [the 7030 ref manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7030/22-6530-2_7030RefMan.pdf).  The terminology is slightly different from the PDP-10; it seems words were divided into fields and fields were divided into bytes of 1 to 8 bits.

Comment: Things got more "interesting" on word-addressing computers after C came along, and you have to implement  variables that are pointers to char, and can support pointer arithmetic. (And of course evil C programmers think all pointer types are really just quiche-eating declarations of "pointer to void"...)

Comment: At one point in my student life, I needed 8-bit character pointers on a 24-bit word-oriented 6-bit-char ICL 1906A.  And this was before I could even spell "C".  (Fortunately the requirement was "make it work" not "make it efficient").

Comment: @alephzero: A major problem with C is that the Standard fails to recognize concepts which are common among many but not all implementations.  If the Standard were to expressly recognize of implementations that offer various features and guarantees that are practical and useful on many but not all platforms, that would make the language more useful for both commonplace and obscure platforms.

Comment: @supercat - tell me about it - where's the operator for _rotate_??  a very useful primitive, implemented in practically every ISA ...  And until "built-in primitives" were invented, compilers either had to figure it out from `((x&15)<<4) | ((x>>28)&15)` (or similar expressions) or ... it didn't figure it out ...

Comment: @davidbak: Back when I dabbled in FORTRAN, I disliked having to use operators like .GE. when using the older keypunches, but C could support a much wider range of useful operators very easily using letter-based tokens.  On many platforms, efficiency could be improved, for example, if there were separate operators for Euclidian division, truncating division, and "Round up or down arbitrarily when using negative operands" division.  If the latter operation were called ADIV, the most efficient way of computing `x .adiv. y` would on many platforms use a divide instruction that performed...

Comment: ...druncating division, but `x .adiv. 4` could simply use a right-shift operator that performed Euclidian division.  In many applications, both results would be equally acceptable, because the operands would never be negative, because the right operand would always divide evenly into the left, or because code didn't need a precise result.  And in cases where code does need some particular kind of result, having an operator for that purpose would be more efficient than having a compiler jump through hoops to round one way, and then having a programmer include code to adjust the result.